# Sencha Touch Clicking anywhere on View changes active item

Tags: xcode4, ios5, cordova, sencha-touch

I am in the process of roughing out an application in Sencha Touch. I'm at the point where I'm verifying that the movement between cards is correct before I add the actual logic for logging in and loading external data.

My problem is that, regardless of which view is active, clicking/tapping anywhere on the view will change the active item to app.views.buildingList.

I am using Sencha Touch 1.1, Phonegap 1.3.0 and XCode 4 (iOS 5 SDK).

Any clues are appreciated!

Viewport.js

```
app.views.Viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
fullscreen: true,
layout: 'card',
cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
initComponent: function() {
Ext.apply(app.views, {
          login: new app.views.Login(),
          plantDetail: new app.views.PlantDetail(),
          buildingList: new app.views.BuildingList()
          });
Ext.apply(this, {
          items: [
                  app.views.login,
                  app.views.plantDetail,
                  app.views.buildingList
                  ]
          });
app.views.Viewport.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Login.js

```
app.views.Login = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
fullscreen: true,

dockedItems: [
    {
        dock : 'top',
        xtype: 'panel',
        height: 70,
        html: '<img src="images/logo.jpg"/>'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name : 'user',
        placeHolder: 'Username',
        cls: 'loginBox',
    },
    {
        xtype: 'passwordfield',
        name : 'password',
        placeHolder: 'Password',
        cls: 'loginBox'         
    },
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text : 'Login',
        cls: 'standardButton',
        listeners: {
            'tap': function () {
                Ext.dispatch({
                    controller: app.controllers.viewController,
                    action: 'index',
                    animation: {type:'slide', direction:'left'}
                });
            }
        }
    },
    {
        xtype: 'spacer',
        html: '<div style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">Forgot Password?</div>' 
    },
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        cls: 'standardButton',
        text : 'Retrieve Password'
    },
    ]

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you have:

```
app.views.Login = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
fullscreen: true, //Only your viewport should be fullscreen
```

Also change your app's name from `app` to something else since that has naming conflicts with android phonegap.